# kinotneとwebhookにて、Kintone側に顧客登録がされるとチャットワーク通知されるようscriptを組んでいたのですが、 急に通知されなくなりました。

Tags: google-apps-script

表題の件について、原因と解決策についてご教示頂きたいです。
サイボウズ社側に問い合わせしたところ、Google App Script で制限を超過したことにより
通知されないのではないかと指摘があったのですが、こちら制限の超過の確認はどのようにできますでしょうか？
また、制限を超過した場合どのように対応すればよろしいでしょうか。
scriptコードについては、APIトークンやチャットルームIDなどが入っておりますため、ご指定頂いたコードをお教えいただけますと、お送りするので大変恐縮ですがご教示頂けますと幸いです。
お手数ですが宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `kinotneとwebhookにて、Kintone側に顧客登録がされるとチャットワーク通知されるようscriptを組んでいた`について、まず状況を理解したいと思います。Google Apps Script側で`doGet`あるいは`doPost`でWeb Appsを設定し、KintoneからWeb AppsへHTTP requestを行うようにしている。この理解でよろしいでしょうか。理解が正しいようですと、`急に通知されなくなりました`ならびに`Google App Script で制限を超過したことにより通知されない`について、この場合、Web Appsへのリクエスト時にエラーが発生しているのでしょうか。それとも、Web Appsへのリクエストは正しく完了している状況下で`チャットワーク通知`が行われないのでしょうか。あるいは、それら以外のエラーが発生しているのでしょうか。まずはここから原因を探るのはいかがでしょうか。詳しい状況が分からず申し訳ありません。